# Cant get js regular expression correct

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get a regular expression to break a string up in to two matches.  here is what I've got so far:  https://jsfiddle.net/9rjzttc2/154/

If I remove one of the`[img url="http://www.technomag.co.zw/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/quiz.jpg"][/img]` it seems to  work.  The gist is that it should read the string, then replace the non html markup with HTML markup, so that each `[img/]` tag becomes an html `<img/>`

Comment: It is much easier to test Regexes with https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `?`, your capture group for the "url" attribute is too greedy (the `.+` is consuming more than you expect it to):

```
/\[(img)\s+(url="(.+?)")\](\w*)\[\/(img)\]/g
//                  ^ this is needed
```

Yours: https://regex101.com/r/IcKhYK/2

This: https://regex101.com/r/IcKhYK/1

[**Working jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9rjzttc2/158/).

Comment: Thank you.  And thanks for showing me regex101, ive been using regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

I updated your regex to the following:

```
var imgMarkup = /\[(img)\s+(url="(.+?)")\](\w*)\[\/(img)\]*/g;
```

It appears to produce what you want? Respond if this is still not accurate.